# What are the different ways of adding Constraint to Python MIP Model?

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to use Python's MIP(Mixed Integer Programming) Module to solve one of my problems. I have gone through the official documentation and some other threads but I wanted to know one thing:

Currently I am using following way to add each constraint:

```
for j in range(10):
    m += xsum(x[i] * (df.loc[((i.SO,i.SI),j)]) for i in P) >= Cap
```

I want to eliminate the inner for loop. is there a better way of adding constraint to model than just using a for loop over variable? This particular way is taking longer time to add because in outer for loop I would have about 300 entries and inner for loop (P) will have a huge number too.

Thanks.

Comment: For MIP models, typically model generation time is much smaller than the time spent to solve the model.

Comment: for me it is the other way, that's why I am trying to find another approach.

Comment: I believe all Python-based modeling tools are somewhat slow. It would be interesting to see how Julia would do on this problem.